# ASP .NET MVC query count issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to run a query on a table (Applications), I'm using the ApplicantId to see if the person has already got a firm offer(the value "True" in the Firm column). Each applicant is only allowed 1 firm application.

```
public void EditApplication(Application application)
{
        Application app = GetOneApplication(application.ApplicationId);
        var Count = 0;

        IQueryable<Application> _firms;
            _firms = from Application
                     in _context.Application
                     where Application.ApplicantId == app.ApplicantId
                     where Application.Firm == true
                     select Application;
        Count = _firms.Count();
        if (Count < 1)
        {
            app.Firm = application.Firm;
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {

        }
}
```

The expected result is to not do anything if a user who already has a Firm application tries to have another firm application.

Comment: What value are you getting for Count?

Comment: It now returns 1, but if I try to change an application (a row) from True to False it doesn't let me, so I need to it block 2 True columns for an Applicant but not the ability to go from True to False

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to count related entities without loading them.  It's very efficient.

```
  var myApp = context.Application.Find(app.ApplicationId);
  var firmsCount = context.Entry(myApp).Collection(x => x.Firms).Query().Count();
  if(firmsCount == 0) {
        //Add a firm to the application
   }
```

Or this is even better, where you don't even have to count them, you just test for the existence of related records.

```
  var myApp = context.Application.Find(app.ApplicationId);
  var firms = context.Entry(myApp).Collection(x => x.Firms).Query().Any();
  if(firms == false) {
        //Add a firm to the application
   }
```

Comment: Tried this but I'm getting a few syntax errors. Things like invalid expression term 'by', Invalid expression '==', the type or namespace having could not be found.

Comment: Sorry, I had given you misleading information before.  Try this one.

Comment: Thanks for the update but I managed to get it fixed, I just needed to add code to the else.